# COS ZF Command return Service

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems-ensemble

In COS I would like to return all the service with a specific name. In command running the command sc queryex type= service state= all | find /i "BFE" and it will display the service name. In COS there is $ZF that can take in a command but it return 0 not sure what i am doing incorrect.

```
USER>s cmd = "sc queryex type= service state= all | find /i ""BFE"""

USER>W cmd
sc queryex type= service state= all | find /i "BFE"
USER>set rc=$zf(-2,cmd)

USER>W rc
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also add that the `$ZF(-1)` and `$ZF(-2)` function is deprecated in the latest version. In the meantime, you can simply append `>> resultfile.txt` to `arg` and then review the file. I would however use `$ZF(-1)` rather than `$ZF(-2)`, which runs the command as a child-process, asynchronously.

Answer (score 3):

in Caché we can call external command with the function `$zf`, where the first argument could be `-1` or `-2`. Where `$zf(-1)` waits, while command will be finished, as a result, will be exit code from this command. `$zf(-2)` does not wait and as a result return `0` if the spawned process was successfully created, and `-1` if not. In your case, you should use `$zf(-1)` because you expecting to get some result immediately. But you have to redirect any output to some temporary file and read it after the call.

Comment: Only if you redirect output to some file. And then you can read it.